# C programming Command Line Argument problem

Tags: c

I'm asked to check command line argument
Without using `strcmp` and the entire `string.h` library
Without using any `[` `]`, i.e. no array operations and only pointers.

How do I check the equality between two strings?
I tried `("String" == *(argv + 1))`, but it doesn't work, `*(argv + 1)` gives me the exact string but the address is different. 
On the other hand, I can't check character by character since it's `char *` instead of `char []`
The type of `agrv` is `char **` instead of `char *[]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   printf("%s", *(argv + 1));
   return 0;
} // Works in the terminal

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc) {
    char ** argv = {"String1", "String2"};
    printf("%s", *(argv + 1));
    return 0;
} // Does not work in IDE, not really understand how char ** works
```

Comment: Please format the question properly and state the problem as described in [ask].

Comment: Exercise 1: check `argc` to establish that you do have an `argv[1]` and print its value. Exercise 2: ditto but print it character by character in a loop. Exercise 3: compare **two** arguments character by character. Step by step, you can get there, and each step will focus the mind on the next step.

Comment: Please show some [MCVE]. So edit your question to improve it

Comment: Notice that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I didn't mean to make it messy, I did type my question in a formatted way, but somehow after I send it out it's scrambled together. It's like all the "\n" are deleted

Comment: Suppose you could use the `<string.h>` functions — how would you write the code then? (You should be using `strcmp()` if you were allowed to, as you hint in the question.) . Now replace `strcmp()` with your own implementation that achieves the same effect — or write a simpler `str_equal()` function to compare whether the two strings are equal and return a boolean.

Comment: @maple, have your tried declaring a variable called something other than `argv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comparing Strings without []

When your lecturer asks you not to use `strcmp()` from `string.h`, it doesn't mean you are forbidden to write your own!

To do this, you have to think about, what `strcmp()` does.  In C strings are basically arrays, that are terminated with `0` -- that means, that the last element in an array is `0`.  So if you go through your array and find such an element, you know you have reached the end.

From your question I assume, that you know how the access to an array by the `[]` operator works.  So I will show you how to compare two strings with the `[]` operator.

```
int my_strcmp(const char * str1, const char * str2)
{
    int idx = 0;

    while (   (str1[idx] == str2[idx])
           && (str1[idx] != 0)
           && (str2[idx] != 0)) {
        ++idx;
    }

    return  str2[idx] - str1[idx];
}
```

So we begin to compare the first elements of both strings.

`(str1[idx] == str2[idx])` checks, if the elements are the same.
`(str1[idx] != 0)` checks, if string 1 is terminated and `(str1[idx] != 0)` checks if string 2 is terminated.  So we stay in the loop while the strings are equal and not ending.

When any of this condition fails, we return the difference of the current element -- consider, that `strcmp()` returns `0` if both strings are equal -- we have the same behaviour in the above function.

The next step is to translate the `[]` access into pointer accesses.  Here you have multiple possibilities.

1. You can increment the string pointers (`++str1;`) and compare dereference them (`*str1`).

   ```
   int my_strcmp(const char * str1, const char * str2)
   {
       while (   (*str1 == *str2)
              && (*str1 != 0)
              && (*str2 != 0)) {
           ++str1;
           ++str2;
       }

       return  *str2 - *str1;
   }
   ```
2. You can use an index (`++idx;`)that is added to the base pointers of the strings and dereference the sum (`*(str1 + idx)`).

   ```
   int my_strcmp(const char * str1, const char * str2)
   {
       int idx = 0;

       while (   (*(str1 + idx) == *(str2 + idx))
              && (*(str1 + idx) != 0)
              && (*(str2 + idx) != 0)) {
           ++idx;
       }

       return  *(str2 + idx) - *(str1 + idx);
   }
   ```

So you only have to use this function in your main function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing parameter\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (my_strcmp(*(argv + 1), "my secret compare string") == 0) {
            printf("argument is equal\n");
        } else {
            printf("argument is unequal\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Pointer to Pointer

What I also see from your question, is that you are not familiar with the `**`.

When we want to store a character, we declare a variable like

```
char v = 'x';
```

In this case, the compiler reserves some space in the RAM, e.g. on address `1003`.  And every time you access the variable `v`, the value of address `1003` is read or written.

```
addr.  value
     +--------+
1002 |   'x'  |
     +--------+
```

If you declare this

```
char * pv = "text2";
```

Multiple things are stored in the RAM.  First the string itself -- consisting of the 5 characters of the string and a terminating `0` -- e.g. on address `1100`.  And additionally a pointer to that array is stored, e.g. on Address `3004`.  On address `3004` the value `1100` is stored -- so the address of the string.

```
addr.  value
     +--------+
1100 |   't'  |<--------+
     +--------+         |
1101 |   'e'  |         |
     +--------+         |
1102 |   'x'  |         |
     +--------+         |
1103 |   't'  |         |
     +--------+         |
1104 |   '2'  |         |
     +--------+         |
1105 |    0   |         |
     +--------+         |
          .             |
          .             |
          .             |
     +--------+         |
3004 |  1100  |---------+
     +--------+
```

And as a last step, you have an array of such pointers.  To address this, you store a pointer to a pointer.

```
char ** ppv = &pv;
```

Here are the strings itself stored (on addresses `1000`, `1100` and `1300`), pointers to these strings (on addresses `3000`, `3004`, `3008`) and as a last element a pointer to the beginning of the array of pointers on address `4192`.

```
addr.  value
     +--------+
1000 |   't'  |<------------+
     +--------+             |
1001 |   'e'  |             |
     +--------+             |
1002 |   'x'  |             |
     +--------+             |
1003 |   't'  |             |
     +--------+             |
1004 |   '3'  |             |
     +--------+             |
1005 |    0   |             |
     +--------+             |
          .                 |
          .                 |
          .                 |
     +--------+
1100 |   't'  |<--------+   |
     +--------+         |   |
1101 |   'e'  |         |   |
     +--------+         |   |
1102 |   'x'  |         |   |
     +--------+         |   |
1103 |   't'  |         |   |
     +--------+         |   |
1104 |   '2'  |         |   |
     +--------+         |   |
1105 |    0   |         |   |
     +--------+         |   |
          .             |   |
          .             |   |
          .             |   |
     +--------+         |   |
1300 |   't'  |<----+   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
1301 |   'e'  |     |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
1302 |   'x'  |     |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
1303 |   't'  |     |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
1304 |   '1'  |     |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
1305 |    0   |     |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
          .         |   |   |
          .         |   |   |
          .         |   |   |
     +--------+     |   |   |
3000 |  1300  |-----+   |   | <------+
     +--------+         |   |        |
3004 |  1100  |---------+   |        |
     +--------+             |        |
3008 |  1000  |-------------+        |
     +--------+                      |
          .                          |
          .                          |
          .                          |
     +--------+                      |
4192 |  3000  |----------------------+
     +--------+
```

So when your process is created by the operating system, it stores all arguments to your program in the ram and a list of pointers to these strings.  And the `argv` is a pointer to this list.

### Declaring an Array of Pointers

To declare an array of pointers you have to use this syntax:

```
const char * arr[] = { "HeLLo", "World!" };
```

But why is your attempt `char ** arr = { "HeLLo", "World" };` not successfull?  You are declaring a variable named `arr`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.  So basically you request the compiler to allocate memory for a pointer.  To make things easier, we will talk about a machine that has 32 bit register width and 32 bit address room.  In this case, a pointer has a size of 4 bytes.

This variable `arr` shall point to a list of pointers to chars, but you don't instruct the compiler to allocate this list.  That is the difference between `char ** x = ...;` and `char * x[] = ...;`.  In the latter case you instruct the compiler to also allocate the memory for the list, not only for the pointer to such a list.

When you have the following (wrong) lines in your code

```
char ** x = { "HeLLo", "World" };
printf("%s\n", x);
```

a compiler could throw the following warning/error:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 --pedantic -Wall -Wextra file.c -o mybin
file.c: In function ‘f’:
file.c:21:16: warning: initialization of ‘char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  char ** x = { "HeLLo", "World" };
                ^~~~~~~
file.c:21:16: note: (near initialization for ‘x’)
file.c:21:25: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char ** x = { "HeLLo", "World" };
                         ^~~~~~~
file.c:21:25: note: (near initialization for ‘x’)
```

I think the warnings/errors are speaking for themselves.

As the first warning explains, your are initializing `x` with the value of `"HeLLo"`, which is a pointer to a string.  The second warning tells you, that you have some dead code, since `"World"` is not used.

When you try to print `x` in the line

```
printf("%s\n", x);
```

you experience some lack of the C language, since it is not type safe here.  The format expression `%s` expects as a parameter the type `char *`.  `x` is of type `char **`.  What you don't see here, that a cast is done.  The value of `x` is not changed but interpreted with different semantics.  This works, since you had a wrong assignment in the first place.

### argc and argv

By convention `argc` tells you the number of arguments, that can be found in `argv`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("argument %d is '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What you have to know is, that the first element (index `0`) is the name of the binary, which could include some path to the binary.  The first parameter in the command line has index `1`, the second command line parameter has index `2` and so on...

Comment: You are very clear in explaining this. I somehow figured parts of it out before I see ur post, but my only question now is how can I define such a double pointer in IDE. char** pp = {"String", "String2"} is obviously not acceptable, what should be the right way to define it if I want to test on my own.

Comment: I tried char **pp = {a,b} just now where a,b are String1 and String2, I noticed that print("%s", pp) will simply print String1. This is weird because argv needs *(argv + 1) to get string address.

Comment: Just a hint:  When you talk about "IDE" or a compiler, please name it.  e.g. gcc for a compiler or eclipse with cdt as the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

This solution satisfies the question's constraints.

I have not commented it, because you provided no code.

Can you figure out how it works? The question is about pointers and pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 3) {
        puts("Not enough arguments");
        return 1;
    }
    char *a1 = *(argv + 1);
    char *a2 = *(argv + 2);

    while(*a1 && *a2 && *a1 == *a2) {
        a1++;
        a2++;
    }

    if(*a1 || *a2) {
        puts("Different");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Same");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like to post minimal complete and verifiable answers. You can check it out for yourself!

Comment: It turns out that your code does give the correct result, but my last problem is how char ** works. I don't understand why *(argv+1) works on char **, if I try to declare char ** inside IDE and run it, it returns error and some strange results.

Answer (score 0):

Array subscripting is just "syntactic sugar", as my old CS professor used to say. The compiler converts `array[i]` to `*(array + i)`. Knowing this, you can use the method of walking the strings character by character to determine equality:

```
const char *compstring = "Example";
const int stringlength = 7; /* length of compstring */
int arg = 1;
int argchar;
int match;
while (*(argv + arg)) /* argv is null-terminated */ {
    argchar = 0;
    match = 1; /* assume they match */
    while (*(*(argv + arg) + argchar)) /* arguments are 0-terminated */ {
        if (argchar == stringlength) /* The string is too long to match */ {
            match = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (*(*(argv + arg) + argchar) != *(compstring + argchar)) /* The characters do not match */ {
            match = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s %s %s", *(argv + arg),
                       (match && argchar == stringlength) ? "matches" : "does not match", /* If the string is the wrong length, it does not match */
                       compstring);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using properly null terminated strings, checking character by character is the best way to go.

```
bool match = false;
char* arg = argv[1];
while(*str && *arg){
  if (*str == *arg) {
    match = true;
    break;
  }
  str++;
  arg++;
}
```

Comment: This logic is backwards, sorry. (If the first characters are the same, you do NOT have a match.) You need to assume that the strings match, and as soon as you find a difference, that's when you do `match=false; break;`. If/when you get to the end of the strings without  difference, then `match` will still be true.

Comment: I'm sorry for being not clear. I'm asking how should I deal with char **. I knew that char * is stored in read-only memories, by incrementing the address I can access each character, but how is char ** stored? I'm assuming that my argument is stored like {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3} in char **. The weird thing is that, using *(argv + 1) can give me the string in the shell, but when I try to do it the same way in IDE (e.g. I set argv ={"String 1", "String 2", "String 3} ) , it is giving me an error.